# magento XML RPC problem Class 'Zend_Http_Client' not found in

Tags: php, magento, xml-rpc, autoload

Any idea on what would make this happen? Im trying to use XML RPC zend version but anytime I try to include the client I get some sort of error. Its like its including the client, but then the client does not know how to include the files after that...

test connect script is located in root directory, with the following -

```
require_once 'lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php';
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://mydomain.com/api/xmlrpc/');
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not, out of the box, automatically load classes for you.  Any PHP class that your script is going to use needs to be required or included into your standalone script.

PHP **does** offer a feature called `__autoload`.  What `__autoload` does is allow you to define a callback function that is invoked whenever an undefined class is loaded.  You can then take action in your function to ensure that the proper class is required or included in.

When you're working within Magento, they've defined autoloader functions for you that take care of loading most module and zend classes.  It sounds like you're writing a stand-alone script, so that won't work for you.

Zend Framework [offers some classes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) to help setup auto loaders.

The simplest solution?  When your script complains about a missing file, require it in yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Ok im confused. The class is in the file Im requiring already, its the first thing declared in the file Client.php is:

    class Zend_XmlRpc_Client
      {

So doesent that mean it should be working???

Comment: Acording to your title the class it can't find it Zend_Http_Client, not Zend_XmlRpc_Client.

Comment: Ok ya my bad. Ok so I went back to including the mage.php file I was originally which should include everything as far as I understand, now I get this error. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_XmlRpc_Client_FaultException' with message 'Calling parameters do not match signature' ..... Zend_XmlRpc_Client->call('login', Array) #1 {main} thrown.... - Any ideas on whats going on there? I checked the login and password and they work fine for me with soap.

Comment: I think the problem there is you're not trying hard enough to solve your own problems.

Comment: Um, well I spent probably 36 hours on that problem before giving up. Maybe youre right, but considering that I have only been writing PHP for probably 3 months or so, there are some gaps in my knowledge, but literally I tried everything I could think of....

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying xmlrpc in a Magento extension.  Finally got it working, here's what you have to put at the start of the file before the class declaration:

```
require_once 'lib/Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
```